# font-face on firefox causes trouble when using font-weight normal

Tags: css, fonts

I've run into an extremely weird bug. I have set up a custom font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyAwesomeFont';
    src: '...';
    font-weight: 'normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyAwesomeFont';
    src: '...';
    font-weight: 'bold;
}
```

There's like 3 more, all with the same name but different `font-weight` (a `bolder`, `100` and `200`). When using the `normal` one, Firefox uses the `bold` one instead - I mean, it doesn't tell me it uses the other one, but other browsers don't behave like that at all...

I tried using an arbitrary value instead of `normal` but that just screwed up things for other browsers. Any ideas what I should try to do?

**update**

I just used exact numbers for all the font-faces. I used 400 for the normal one, so technically it's the same. But now Firefox renders it correctly. I'm very unsure as to what exactly happened...

Comment: Also, there's no cross-site problems here. It's all on the same domain and FF is not complaining. It just automatically does stuff I didn't ask it to and makes everything ugly

Comment: Have you tried using the number weights? What happens if you change `normal` to `500` in your `@font-face` and your css?

Comment: I do not really understand your problem. Please keep in mind that `font-weight: normal` equals to `400`! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: @Netsurfer The problem is not that it's 400, the problem is it's rendered a lot bolder in FF than on other browsers

Comment: @nwalton yeah. That solved it - I just used specific numbers all the way. I can't say why that helped though. configuring the font-face to 400 instead of normal shouldn't actually change anything, but it did...

Comment: [Maybe this could help](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/)

Comment: @yuvi Yeah, it depends on your font files (which font file is actually used for a certain thickness). That's e.g. why a link to Google's web fonts looks like this: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: @Netsurfer I used font-squirrel to make sure I source all formats... I guess FF just chose the wrong one

Comment: @yuvi Have you used the Font Generator or downloaded a ready made kit? And we are only talking about the WOFF format. So could check if a file is OK by using Chrome (or any other browser supporting the woff format). But make sure that only the WOFF files are available and that the font is not locally installed on your system! Is the font in question exactly for a 400 font weight? And are all used characters available in your font?

Comment: @Netsurfer I used the Font Generator. I already had it in one format, and creating the rest fixed most of the troubles I had with cross browsers. So no, not only WOFF files are available. FS was nice enough to also automatically create a css file with the correct imports.

Comment: @yuvi Yes, but for testing you should only use the WOFF files to ensure that not the TTF ones are used instead. And personally I had problems with FS e.g. when base64 encoding a WOFF file formerly generated with FS generator but originated from Google's web fonts. Use your browsers developer tool to see, if the appropriate font file is loaded correctly (in the preview you should see all characters of the font). I never heard about any bugs (in FF) dealing with `@font-face`. So if things went wrong it is most presumably that there is something wrong either with your CSS or the font file itself.

Comment: @Netsurfer Thanks, it's very clarifying. For now, being specific about the `font-weight` does a good enough job for me, but I'll definitely keep all that in mind. You can summarize your comments to an answer if you'd like, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @yuvi That's very kind of you - done! BTW: I just have recognized that you have used commas instead of semicolons in your posted CSS code. Is it a typo ...?

Comment: @Netsurfer Well you helped me a lot. Also yeah heh... it's a typo =P Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using your "own" fonts, respectively make sure that a certain font is available you should follow certain things.

Firstly how to use `@font-face`:
Always use a number (100 - 900) for the font-weight and also define the font-style (most fonts have separate files for normal and italic (for different thickness = font-weight)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyAwesomeFont';
    src: '...';
    font-weight: 400; /* 'normal' equals to '400' */
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyAwesomeFont';
    src: '...';
    font-weight: 700; /* 'bold' depends on your available font files, normally it is equal to '700' */
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You'll find some further information about `font-weight` on this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

If the desired font is not loaded, you can check the following points:

1. Make sure that only the needed format (e.g. WOFF) is given in the source and use the developer tool of your browser to check if the file is loaded correctly and watch the preview (should show all available characters of the given font).
2. The desired font must not be available/ installed on your test/ local system.
3. If you have generated the font files using a "Font Generator" (like Font Squirrel's) re-do the process (because maybe the file was corrupted). If this doesn't help, try to find another source file (in most cases the TTF file of the font) and use this for generating the other formats. If this still doesn't solve your problem go and use another "Font Generator".

Also ensure that all used characters are in the subset of your font file(s).

If you still encounter any problems come here again and let us know. ;-)

Good luck and success!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "**bolder**" and "**lighter**" statement. Somehow @font-face doesn't play nice with those font-weight declaration.

I was playing around, trying to figure out why my regular font was bold all the time. The order of the font-face declaration also made a difference, but still it acted weird.

Then I replaced the "bolder" statement with a number "900", and suddenly everything worked as it should.

I didn't find any other blogs talking about this problem yet. This issue happens in Firefox, Chrome and at least IE11.

Although IE11 doesn't seem to play nice with the "lighter" statement.

**So to be sure, just use numbers (100 to 900) or bold. not bolder or lighter**